# How to detect only digit ,'(' , ')' ,'+' in Javascript String

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to detect if a JavaScript `String` contains one of these following characters :

- a digit ( 0 to 9)
- the '(' character
- the ')' character

How can i do that ?

Comment: Though you've got an answer, it seems like your question might get closed - some ways you might improve it visually include using backtick quoting around the characters you ask about instead of apostrophes. To be a bit less broad, you might clarify if you want the string to contain _only_ one of those characters, or if you want the string to contain _any_ one of those characters (plus more characters?). A little bit of context and an _example of what you've tried_ is also good.

Comment: Seems like 'do my work' kind of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s = 'your string';
if (/[0-9()+]/.test(s)) {
  // match
}
```

`0-9` can be written as `\d`

```
if (/[\d()+]/.test(s)) {}
```

Your question is inconsistent. If you want to test if string is '0' or '1' ... or '(':

```
if (/^[\d()+]$/.test(s)) {}
```

Read about RegEp here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: +1 for not needlessly escaping `()+`